# Что такое оценочные приложения?

Tags: untagged

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где найти определение термина, или дайте его в ответе.
Сам я не сумел найти *оценочные приложения* в Интернете.

Comment: Например: *самолёт-красавец*. Когда мы оцениваем что-то, сторону чего-то. По ходу, это не официальный термин.

Comment: Чтобы понять что такое "оценочные приложения", нужно знать что такое приложения в русском языке.

Comment: А красавец самолет пишется без дефиса и это значит, что это не оценочное суждение?

Comment: Тоже оценочное. Зависит от самого слова. Написание такое, потому что похоже на "красивый самолёт".

Comment: @Зонтик , Термин приложение имеет весьма понятное определение: *Приложение — это определение, выраженное существительным, согласованным с определяемым словом в падеже, например: Ночевала тучка золотая на груди утеса-великана. Приложения могут обозначать различные качества предмета, указывать на возраст, национальность, профессию и другие признаки ...*   но это не помогает понять, что такое оценочное определение, которое должно писаться с дефисом по Лопатину (§ 120 в) ).

Comment: Не могу понять, почему минусовали этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

**1. ПАС под редакцией Лопатина** http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65#pp65

§ 120. Следующие разряды существительных и сочетания существительных пишутся через дефис:
в) *сочетания с однословными приложениями, предшествующими определяемому слову, напр.: старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик, мудрец-писатель, проказница-мартышка, самодурка-мачеха, трудяга-следователь, профан-редактор, пройдоха-управляющий.* Такие приложения носят **оценочный характер.**

**2. Правила Розенталя**
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111
Пункт 2. Примечания: 4. Дефис не пишется:
**1)** если предшествующее однословное приложение может быть по значению **приравнено к определению-прилагательному:** *красавец мужчина* (ср.: *красивый мужчина*), *старик отец, гигант завод* (но: *завод-гигант*), *бедняк сапожник, богатырь всадник, крошка сиротка, хищник волк, искусник повар.*

Такая же формулировка **в  правилах 1956 года.**

**3. Не очень ясна фраза:** «приложение может быть по значению приравнено к определению-прилагательному».

Ее можно понимать так. Как прилагательные, так и приложения могут быть разного вида, нас же интересует **тот вариант, где они имеют сходное значение.** Это качественные прилагательные и приложения, называющие качественные признаки и свойства. (Значения приложений даны в Грамматике 1990 года под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина.)

В ПАС про эту группу сказано: такие приложения носят **оценочный характер.**

**4.** Розенталь **упоминает этот термин**  в  разделе «сложные существительные»
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=48#pp48
Пункт 2. Пишутся через дефис:
**7)** сложные слова, в которых к основному слову присоединяется слово **с оценочным значением**: бой-баба, гоп-компания, горе-руководитель, паинька-мальчик, чудо-рыба, ура-патриотизм.

**5. Примечание.** Интересно, что термин «оценочный» используется в **классификации суффиксов:**  В русском языке существуют два вида суффиксов существительных: суффиксы субъективной оценки (оценочные суффиксы) и словообразовательные суффиксы.

Comment: Цельно оно не произносится, так что Розенталь прав.

Comment: Это вы про что?

Comment: Про примеры Розенталя.

Comment: Это уточнение моего ответа?

Comment: Я хорошая, если меня не злить.

Comment: А вы не доводите до этого своими действиями.